New Angular project, but the ng serve default page does not look like it should
I started learning Angular a week ago. I initialized a project with ng new and then after i entered ng serve to check the default page of the app, I got this page :
ng serve default project page
The app still works so that's okay, but I wonder why this presentation is not the same as the 'usual' default page below :
'normal' ng serve default project page
I did not try anything as my Angular knowledge is pretty much non-existing at this point, but I looked online and did not see any page that remotely looks like what I got when I started my project.
It could be some kind of new presentation from newer Angular versions but did not find any clue leading to that theory.
I'm sure it's nothing to worry about, but how do I get my angular app to display the 'real' default project page ?
Thanks for your time !

This might be a change in 17? I found a rando site that has the same page as you: https://benbelson.com/. Inspecting the page, I can see that they're running Angular 17. I agree with you that I'm used to seeing that old page, but I also haven't created a new Angular app lately.

This is just a temporary placeholder which is to be removed when implementing the real application. Angular may update this placeholder as per changes to the Corporate Identity. For example, the logo was recently changed and the documentation page was completely re-designed.

The app component placeholder for newly generated applications via ng new was updated in v17 (feature update ng new generated application under @schematics/angular).
It's part of the v17 Angular renaissance / new branding
References:

Commit introducing changes
PR introducing changes

